# fatal: Not a valid object name: 'refs/remotes/trunk'

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

After using `git svn` with clone and fetches I end with a local git repository that looks as follows. Note that I have made a first push to my Git server Atlassian's Stash but as result I only have in-sync with the git server the master branch:

```
c:\myproject>git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/1335-branch
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/tags/0.1
  remotes/origin/trunk
```

Following direction from [Migrating from SVN to Git ...](http://www.sailmaker.co.uk/blog/2013/05/05/migrating-from-svn-to-git-preserving-branches-and-tags-3/) and trying to convert the remote svn branches to local Git branches I do:

```
c:\myproject>git branch origin/trunk refs/remotes/trunk
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'refs/remotes/trunk'.
```

and then I get the OP error `fatal: Not a valid object name: 'refs/remotes/trunk'` and I can't see why it happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tutorial is probably made with a different version of `git-svn`. Formerly the `--prefix` was empty by default, in newer versions it is `origin/` by default. Because of that you have now `refs/remotes/origin/trunk` and so on instead of `refs/remotes/trunk`.